# Does Ansible create a thread for each host in inventory when running a playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

How does Ansible playbook works with inventory?

I have 5 machines and we have an playbook `check_ssh_access.yml`.  That playbook checks ssh connection to those machines.

Does Ansible create 5 threads with same playbook for those 5 machines or run playbook on each machine in one after other?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on selected [strategy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_strategies.html).

By default `linear` strategy is used, so Ansible will make as much threads as [forks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#forks) option allow.